# GoogleCloud: With service account credentials, how to access all files under directory ? How to get SignedUrl for entire directory?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, gsutil

Google Cloud:
I have stored some files under `xyz` folder which is under `ABC` bucket. We have created service account to access those files. I am able to create signed URL for each file with `gsutil`:

```
gsutil signurl -d 120s key.json gs://bucketname/folderNmae/index.html
```

Instead of creating `signedURL` for all files I want to access directly folder.
Do we have any solution to do that?

Tried creating `signedURL` for folder but got error:

> Please create/upload an object with that name before a creating signed URL to access it.

Comment: Hello, GCS works based on objects. I'm afraid that what you are asking for it's not possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following command to achieve that functionality:

```
gsutil signurl -d 120s key.json gs://bucketname/folderName/**
```

This will create a SignedURL for each of the files inside your bucket.

More information about using Wildcard Names in gsutil commands can be found in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames) from the documentation.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The command in this answer will generate a URL for each object in the bucket folder and does NOT generate a single URL for all files in a bucket as asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

GCS doesn't have honest-to-goodness subdirectories; you have objects with names that may have similar prefixes containing `/` characters, which look like directories in a path.  Today, using signed URLs, you can't grant access to any/all objects starting with a given prefix. You can only grant someone permission to make an authenticated API call against a specific resource.